# How to push logs from kubernetes to elastic cloud deployment?

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes, logstash, elk, elastic-cloud

I am trying to configure **logstash** and **filebeat** running in kubernetes to connect and push logs from kubernetes cluster to my deployment in the **elastic cloud**.
I have configured the **logstash.yaml** file with *host*, *username* and *password*, please find the config below:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: logstash-config
  namespace: ns-elastic
data:
  logstash.conf: |-
    input {
      beats {
          port => "9600"
      }
    }

    filter {

      fingerprint {
        source => "message"
        target => "[@metadata][fingerprint]"
        method => "MURMUR3"
      }  

      # Container logs are received with variable named index_prefix
      # Since it is in json format, we can decode it via json filter plugin.
      if [index_prefix] == "store-logs" {

        if [message] =~ /^\{.*\}$/ {
          json {
            source => "message"
            skip_on_invalid_json => true
          }
        }

      }
      if [index_prefix] == "ingress-" {

        if [message] =~ /^\{.*\}$/ {
          json {
            source => "message"
            skip_on_invalid_json => true
          }
        }

      }

      # do not expose index_prefix field to kibana
      mutate {
        # @metadata is not exposed outside of Logstash by default.
        add_field => { "[@metadata][index_prefix]" => "%{index_prefix}-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}" }
        # since we added index_prefix to metadata, we no longer need ["index_prefix"] field.
        remove_field => ["index_prefix"]
      }

    }

    output {
      # You can uncomment this line to investigate the generated events by the logstash.
      stdout { codec => rubydebug }
      elasticsearch {
          hosts => "https://******.es.*****.azure.elastic-cloud.com:9243"
          user => "username"
          password => "*****************"
          document_id => "%{[@metadata][fingerprint]}" 
          # The events will be stored in elasticsearch under previously defined index_prefix value.
          index => "%{[@metadata][index_prefix]}"
      }              
    }
```

However, the logstash restarts with the below error:

```
[2022-06-19T17:32:31,943][INFO ][org.logstash.beats.Server][main][3cdfe6dec21f50e50e275d7a0c7a3d34d8ead0610c72e80ef9c735c2ef53beb9] Starting server on port: 9600
[2022-06-19T17:32:38,154][ERROR][logstash.javapipeline    ][main][3cdfe6dec21f50e50e275d7a0c7a3d34d8ead0610c72e80ef9c735c2ef53beb9] A plugin had an unrecoverable error. Will restart this plugin.
  Pipeline_id:main
  Plugin: <LogStash::Inputs::Beats port=>9600, id=>"3cdfe6dec21f50e50e275d7a0c7a3d34d8ead0610c72e80ef9c735c2ef53beb9", enable_metric=>true, codec=><LogStash::Codecs::Plain id=>"plain_4b2c91f6-9a6f-4e5e-9a96-5b42e20cd0d9", enable_metric=>true, charset=>"UTF-8">, host=>"0.0.0.0", ssl=>false, add_hostname=>false, ssl_verify_mode=>"none", ssl_peer_metadata=>false, include_codec_tag=>true, ssl_handshake_timeout=>10000, tls_min_version=>1, tls_max_version=>1.3, cipher_suites=>["TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256", "TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384", "TLS_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256", "TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384", "TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384", "TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256", "TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256", "TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256", "TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256", "TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384", "TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384", "TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256", "TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256"], client_inactivity_timeout=>60, executor_threads=>1>
  Error: Address already in use
  Exception: Java::JavaNet::BindException
  Stack: sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(sun/nio/ch/Net.java:459)
sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(sun/nio/ch/Net.java:448)
sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(sun/nio/ch/ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:227)
io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerSocketChannel.doBind(io/netty/channel/socket/nio/NioServerSocketChannel.java:134)
io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.bind(io/netty/channel/AbstractChannel.java:562)
io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.bind(io/netty/channel/DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1334)
io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeBind(io/netty/channel/AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:506)
io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.bind(io/netty/channel/AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:491)
io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.bind(io/netty/channel/DefaultChannelPipeline.java:973)
io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel.bind(io/netty/channel/AbstractChannel.java:260)
io.netty.bootstrap.AbstractBootstrap$2.run(io/netty/bootstrap/AbstractBootstrap.java:356)
io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(io/netty/util/concurrent/AbstractEventExecutor.java:164)
io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(io/netty/util/concurrent/SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:472)
io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(io/netty/channel/nio/NioEventLoop.java:500)
io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(io/netty/util/concurrent/SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989)
io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(io/netty/util/internal/ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(io/netty/util/concurrent/FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
java.lang.Thread.run(java/lang/Thread.java:829)
```

Can anyone please help me understand what I am doing incorrectly here? My endgoal is to push logs from my kubernetes cluster to my deployment of elasticsearch service on Elastic Cloud. Please assist as I am unable to get enough resources on this.

Answer (score 0):

The error we see in your logs says:

```
Error: Address already in use
Exception: Java::JavaNet::BindException
```

This means there is already a process that binds on port TCP/9600.

You could use `netstat -plant` to inspect services listening on your host. Could be another instance of logstash that was not properly shut down.

Comment: I tried changing port from 9600 to 9700. However, now I am getting a message "elasticsearch: Temporary failure in name resolution". I tried changing the hostname to IP instead though it is also not working. 
Also, I see the host is trying to reach "http://elasticsearch:9200/" instead of "https://******.es.*****.azure.elastic-cloud.com:9243".

Comment: Logs from logstash pod:
[2022-06-20T05:59:48,226][INFO ][logstash.licensechecker.licensereader] Failed to perform request {:message=>"elasticsearch: Temporary failure in name resolution", :exception=>Manticore::ResolutionFailure, :cause=>java.net.UnknownHostException: elasticsearch: Temporary failure in name resolution}

Comment: [2022-06-20T05:59:48,226][WARN ][logstash.licensechecker.licensereader] Attempted to resurrect connection to dead ES instance, but got an error {:url=>"http://elasticsearch:9200/", :exception=>LogStash::Outputs::ElasticSearch::HttpClient::Pool::HostUnreachableError, :message=>"Elasticsearch Unreachable: [http://elasticsearch:9200/][Manticore::ResolutionFailure] elasticsearch: Temporary failure in name resolution"}
[2022-06-20T06:00:05,554][ERROR][logstash.licensechecker.licensereader] Unable to retrieve license information from license server {:message=>"No Available connections"}

Comment: Feel free to edit your initial post with that new error. Though I'm not sure I know the answer to that one. Check configurations inside your container, that `elasticsearch:9200` is obviously defined somewhere. Nothing in your initial post suggests it could be here. Then again, we don't know what image you're using, how configuration is attached, how you start logstash, ...